# puzzling one for my 11 year old and myself

Tags: mathematics

$\frac{1}{4}$ of the marbles in a box are blue. There are $24$ more red marbles than blue marbles in the box. The remaining $32$ marbles are yellow. How many red marbles are in the box?

Comment: It sounds like this is a textbook-style math problem and not a puzzle. Does this belong in https://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that this can even be in Math.SE. I mean, this is like a math question for middle schoolers

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can solve this with:

> algebra! (cheer)

So,

> let x equal the number of blue marbles.

The number of red marbles is

> x+24

and the total number of marbles is

> x+x+24+32, or 2x+56 marbles.

Since the number of blue marbles is 1/4th the total,

> (2x+56)/4 = x

Algebra gives

> 2x+56 = 4x 
>  56 = 2x 
>  x = 28

Since

> the number of red marbles is x+24, there are **52** red marbles in the box.

Comment: sorry for posting a math problem rather that a puzzle wasn't clear on the difference though but thanks for solving it. it really was a mind buggler. plus it made me clear that it was not a problem for an 11year old who has not even ventured into algebra. thanks Excited Raichu. oh yeah can you recommed a site for stuff like these.